# Angular JS pagination service not updating ng-repeat values properly

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, pagination

I'm trying to implement a pagination service in my angular app from this [tutorial](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/01/31/AngularJS-Pagination-Example-with-Logic-like-Google.aspx), and the ultimate goal is to display 10 links per page. A link usually contains a title, a description, and an image. However, there are some links that doesn't contain a image, and this is where the problem occurs.

Here is the sample CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rLbZyY

The pagination service:

```
function PagerService() {
    // service definition
    var service = {};

    service.GetPager = GetPager;

    return service;

    // service implementation
    function GetPager(totalItems, currentPage, pageSize) {
        // default to first page
        currentPage = currentPage || 1;

        // default page size is 10
        pageSize = pageSize || 10;

        // calculate total pages
        var totalPages = Math.ceil(totalItems / pageSize);

        var startPage, endPage;
        if (totalPages <= 10) {
            // less than 10 total pages so show all
            startPage = 1;
            endPage = totalPages;
        } else {
            // more than 10 total pages so calculate start and end pages
            if (currentPage <= 6) {
                startPage = 1;
                endPage = 10;
            } else if (currentPage + 4 >= totalPages) {
                startPage = totalPages - 9;
                endPage = totalPages;
            } else {
                startPage = currentPage - 5;
                endPage = currentPage + 4;
            }
        }

        // calculate start and end item indexes
        var startIndex = (currentPage - 1) * pageSize;
        var endIndex = Math.min(startIndex + pageSize - 1, totalItems - 1);

        // create an array of pages to ng-repeat in the pager control
        var pages = _.range(startPage, endPage + 1);

        // return object with all pager properties required by the view
        return {
            totalItems: totalItems,
            currentPage: currentPage,
            pageSize: pageSize,
            totalPages: totalPages,
            startPage: startPage,
            endPage: endPage,
            startIndex: startIndex,
            endIndex: endIndex,
            pages: pages
        };
    }
}
```

The page setting function:

```
function setPage(page) {
    if (page < 1 || page > vm.pager.totalPages) {
            return;
    }
    // get pager object from service
    vm.pager = PagerService.GetPager(vm.dummyItems.length, page);

    // get current page of items
    vm.items = vm.dummyItems.slice(vm.pager.startIndex, vm.pager.endIndex + 1);
}
```

As you can see in the CodePen, when a link doesn't contain an image, it simply shows nothing. However, on the web, it displays the image of the previous link. For example, link No.17 doesn't have an image, it displays the image of link No.7 instead of nothing, while I prefer displaying nothing.

I've tried adding `$scope.$apply();` to the bottom of `function setPage(page)` and it doesn't do the trick. Now I'm adding a `ng-if` for a temporary solution, and asking why this problem happens and if there's any other solution.

The problem is quite complicated, please tell me if I should add any other codes or description to make the problem clearer.

Comment: Does the array in your deployed application also include elements of the array that are empty? In other words, in your array, if there is an element without an image does it not contain a flag to signal there is no image?

Comment: @Mike I'm not sure if I fully understand your question but if the element does not have an image, I did not add another variable to detect and signal it